# Plot datetime vs values using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have three columns "Date", "Time" and "Values" which I need to plot.

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\markl\OneDrive\Dokument\Downloads\file.xlsx') 


df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date')) + pd.to_timedelta(df.pop('Time')) 
#Combine columns "Date" and "Time"

df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
```

this yeilds the Value error: time data '2021-02-22 12:31:59' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'

Why is this??

Comment: Remove `.%f`. Obviously, '12:31:59' does not match '%H:%M:%S.%f'. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the ".%f" at the end of the format strings means that it is expecting some sort of microsecond number after the seconds number, whereas your time data appears to stop after the seconds number. I did the following and it works:

```
import datetime

string = "2021-02-22 12:31:59"
datetime.datetime.strptime(string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```